# How to call a javascript function along with scope from Actionscript?

Tags: javascript, actionscript, dojo

I could call a javascript global function from ActionScript using ExternalInterface. Can I somehow call scope.method() instead without making the global function call scope.method() inside it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did something similar (I think) previously...

In Javascript:

```
function SomeObject()
{
    this.someMethod = function()
    {
        //do something...
    }
}

var obj = new SomeObject();
```

In actionscript:

```
ExternalInterface.call("obj.someMethod");
```